# Analyzing SQL time series for event occurence

Tags: plsql, time-series

I’m trying to come up with a solution for a specific time series analysis in PL/SQL. I’ll use a very simple data set to explain the scenario.
In the COMP_TEST table an event gets a row created for it as long as there are individual calendar days (CAL_DATE) between the EVENT_START_DATE and EVENT_END_DATE. In case of EVENT_ID 1772349 we get rows for 10/01/2020 – 10/24/2020 since that is the start and end range.
On each given calendar day, the results of some event are recorded as ‘yes’ or ‘no’ in the EVENT_RESULT column.

Requirements to check:

- There should be a ‘yes’ EVENT_RESULT every 7 calendar days.
- There should not be more than 7 calendar days between two ‘yes’
  results.
- A consecutive 7 calendar day block of ‘no’ results will get counted
  as one unit of non-compliance/deficiency.
- Every time a ‘yes’ result is encountered, the count for evaluating
  the next 7 calendar days for the ‘no’ results should reset back to 1.
- If a ‘no’ result is encountered on the CAL_DATE that is equal to the
  EVENT_END_DATE then that will count as one unit of
  non-compliance/deficiency as well

NOTE: 7 calendar days here should be start and end dates inclusive.

In the case of EVENT_ID 1772349 the first CAL_DATE 01-OCT-20 had a ‘yes’ result so the next 7 calendar day evaluation would start at 02-OCT-20 (day 1) and end at 08-OCT-20 (day 7) where the ‘yes’ result was recorded.
The second evaluation would start with 09-OCT-20 which happens to be a ‘yes’ result also so the next count would actually begin with 10-OCT-20 where the result was a ‘no’ and continued to be ‘no’ till 16-OCT-20 for 7 consecutive days.
Then the third evaluation would begin with 17-OCT-20 after which there was only one additional ‘no’ result on 18-OCT-20 and then all days 19-OCT-20 to 23-OCT-20 were ‘yes’ results. Finally on the last calendar day of the event 24-OCT-20 we hit a ‘no’ which would get classified as a deficiency.

I have included the create table script, query that I’ve attempted, and expected outputs below. Since this sounded to fit the gaps and islands problem I started with that approach but didn’t know how to tackle the rest of the requirements.

TABLE CREATE SCRIPT:

```
CREATE TABLE COMP_TEST ( 
event_id INT 
,cal_date DATE 
,event_result varchar2(5) 
,event_start_date DATE 
,event_end_date DATE 
)
```

TABLE INSERTS:

```
INSERT ALL 
 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'yes',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/02/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/03/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/04/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/05/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/06/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/07/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/08/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'yes',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/09/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'yes',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/10/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/11/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/12/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/13/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/14/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/16/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/17/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/18/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/19/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'yes',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/20/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'yes',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/21/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'yes',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/22/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'yes',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/23/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'yes',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (1772349,TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/16/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/17/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/18/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/19/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/20/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/21/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/22/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/23/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'yes',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'yes',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/25/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/26/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/27/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/28/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/29/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/30/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('10/31/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'yes',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/02/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/03/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/04/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/04/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/05/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/06/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/07/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/08/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/09/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/10/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/11/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/12/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/13/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL) 
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/14/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL)
INTO COMP_TEST  (event_id, cal_date, event_result, event_start_date, event_end_date)    VALUES (5499345,TO_DATE('11/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'no',TO_DATE('10/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL)
SELECT * FROM DUAL
```

QUERY THAT I TRIED:

```
WITH DAILY_RESULT AS ( 
SELECT 
    event_id 
    , cal_date 
    , CASE 
        WHEN event_result = 'yes' THEN 'compliant'  
        WHEN event_result = 'no' THEN 'deficient'  
        END AS status 
FROM COMP_TEST 
), 
 
RANKINGS AS ( 
SELECT 
    event_id 
    , cal_date 
    , status AS status 
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY cal_date) - 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY event_id, status ORDER BY cal_date) 
        AS sequence_grouping 
FROM DAILY_RESULT 
ORDER BY cal_date ASC 
) 
 
SELECT 
    event_id 
    , MIN(cal_date) AS start_date 
    , MAX(cal_date) AS end_date 
    , MAX(cal_date) - MIN(cal_date) AS duration 
     
FROM RANKINGS 
WHERE status = 'deficient' 
 
GROUP BY  
    event_id 
    , sequence_grouping 

HAVING MAX(cal_date) - MIN(cal_date) >=7
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
EVENT_ID - START_DATE - END_DATE
1772349 -- 10/10/2020 -- 10/16/2020
1772349 -- 10/24/2020 -- 10/24/2020
5499345 -- 10/15/2020 -- 10/21/2020
5499345 -- 10/25/2020 -- 10/31/2020
5499345 -- 11/02/2020 -- 11/08/2020
5499345 -- 11/09/2020 -- 11/15/2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is does what you want, but I wasn't able to figure out what you are asking for on `deficient_cnt`.  Also, your question could use a little formatting because it's really hard to read and understand the requirements.  Thank you for providing a `CREATE TABLE` and DML statements.

Okay, PL/SQL solution which I think is a lot simpler.  You could do this with one loop, but I think to explain what is going on two makes it more clear.  If you don't have a ton of data then it probably doesn't matter.

We go through each event (outer loop) and then the data per day for that event (inner loop).  I did notice you put in two rows for `event_id` 5499345 for 11/4/2020 (not sure if that was intentional), but the `GROUP BY` on the inner loop handles that: using MAX() will prefer a `'yes'` over a `'no'`.  We then simply count consecutive `'no'` values advancing the end date of the range as we go.  Encountering a `'yes'` value resets the counter and hitting 7 days prints the result and also resets.  There is one last test of the counter after the inner loop for dangling `'no'` values at the end of the data set for a given `event_id`.

```
DECLARE
  v_cal_date_ct INTEGER;
  v_start_date  comp_test.cal_date%TYPE;
  v_end_date    comp_test.cal_date%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR rec_event IN (SELECT DISTINCT ct.event_id
                      FROM comp_test ct
                     ORDER BY ct.event_id)
  LOOP
    v_cal_date_ct := 0;
  
    FOR rec_date IN (SELECT ct.cal_date,
                            MAX(ct.event_result) AS event_result
                       FROM comp_test ct
                      WHERE ct.event_id = rec_event.event_id
                      GROUP BY ct.cal_date
                      ORDER BY ct.cal_date)
    LOOP
      IF v_cal_date_ct = 0 THEN
        v_start_date := rec_date.cal_date;
        v_end_date   := rec_date.cal_date;
      END IF;
    
      IF rec_date.event_result = 'no' THEN
        v_cal_date_ct := v_cal_date_ct + 1;
        v_end_date    := rec_date.cal_date;
      ELSE
        v_cal_date_ct := 0;
      END IF;
    
      IF v_cal_date_ct >= 7 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(rec_event.event_id || ' ' ||
                             to_char(v_start_date,
                                     'mm/dd/yyyy') || ' ' ||
                             to_char(v_end_date,
                                     'mm/dd/yyyy'));
        v_cal_date_ct := 0;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  
    IF v_cal_date_ct > 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(rec_event.event_id || ' ' ||
                           to_char(v_start_date,
                                   'mm/dd/yyyy') || ' ' ||
                           to_char(v_end_date,
                                   'mm/dd/yyyy'));
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Results:

```
1772349 10/10/2020 10/16/2020
1772349 10/24/2020 10/24/2020
5499345 10/15/2020 10/21/2020
5499345 10/25/2020 10/31/2020
5499345 11/02/2020 11/08/2020
5499345 11/09/2020 11/15/2020
```

Lastly, remember to do a `SET serveroutput ON` in SQL*Plus to see the results.  If you wanted to build yourself a table to INSERT into or turn this into a pipelined function the same logic would work.

Comment: Thank you @kevin-seymour. I will pay attention to the formatting. The deficient_cnt is something I'll use later to sum up counts by event_id so that is quite simple for me to add. I will check out your solution over the weekend and get back to you.

Thank you again!

Comment: I inserted some additional records for EVENT_ID 5499345 (CAL_DATE past 11/01/2020) and this query only seems to get two records per EVENT_ID only. There will be cases where an EVENT_ID may have several 7 day consecutive periods that will need to be identified.

Comment: Can you update your expected results to match the new rows you added?  Additionally, my query is not constrained to two rows per `event_id`: your example only has two per.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for getting back so quickly. I have updated the insert statement and expected results in my question .

Comment: Thanks.  One last question: are you looking for a pure SQL option or would a PL/SQL option also be acceptable?  It might be simpler to do what you want procedurally (especially for the last case of `event_id` 5499345).

Comment: PL/SQL option would be great.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the solution in detail, it makes sense. I can modify this for my production data now. The duplicate row for 11/04/2020 was a mistake in my insert statement. Once again, I really appreciate your time and all the help!